# When did colspan and rowspan become available for usage in HTML tables?

Tags: html, html-table, language-history

A co-worker and I are curious about when `colspan` and `rowspan` became available for usage in HTML tables.

We tried Google and Wikipedia, but the answer still seems to elude us.

I thought it might have been since HTML 2, or early-to-mid-90s, but he insists it wasn't until 2000 or later....

Comment: How hard did you actually try Google?  I mean, it took me like 3 searches to find the old HTML specs.

Comment: Sounds like you won the debate, congrats!

Comment: @Pointy - We both searched but obviously we used the wrong terms. We found out a lot of information but we could not find an exact date. Some people should just keep their comments to themselves but everyone's tough on the Internet.

Thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RFC 1942 introduced tables in May 96, the rfc includes rowspans so this is the earliest official document implementing them.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1942

Edit - Should mention that this is a refinement for html 2.0

Answer (score 1):

They're mentioned in versions of the HTML 4 spec as far back as 1997 at least. *edit* They're also in HTML 3; they seem to have been around as long as `<table>` itself.

Answer (score 1):

As far as W3C is concerned, it looks like HTML 3.2, so January 1997. Both attributes are mentioned in the [3.2 spec](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/tables.html), but I don't see them anywhere in the [2.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_toc.html).

If you're not strictly following W3C, the answer seems to be **May 1996**. See the example at the top of page 2 of [RFC 1942](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1942), which adds support for tables.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533581%28VS.85%29.aspx), they are defined in [HTML 3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32), which is dated 14 Jan 1997. So, a long way back.

Answer (score 0):

Well they are in HTML3: http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/tables.html